# C++ how to modify a struct using a call from another function

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to understand how to write a function that can modify a `struct`. I want to add a day to my `struct` Date. However, the `addOneDay` function below doesn't work.

My goal is to `addOneDay` to my birthday, using a function. How do I manipulate the data in the struct to get `addOneDay` to work?

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct Date
    {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    };


    Date addOneDay(const Date& date);

    Date addOneDay(const Date& date)
    {
        Date rdate = date.day+1; /* <- this doesn't work */
        return rdate;
    };

void assignValues(Date& myBirthday)
{
    myBirthday.day = 27;
    myBirthday.month = 1;
    myBirthday.year = 1962;
}

main()
{
    Date x;
    assignValues(x);

    cout << x.month << "/" << x.day << "/" << x.year << endl;

    //addOneDay(x)
};
```

Comment: Can you post an error message? It saves people from having to compile it to see the error for themselves.

Comment: Sure, thing. The compiler says: No viable conversion from 'int' to 'Date'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong. As you found out.

```
Date rdate = date.day+1; /* <- this doesn't work */
```

Because you are assigning an integer value to a date object and as it stands the compiler doesn't know how to do that conversion.

You need to assign the value back to the `day` field of `Date` like

```
date.day += 1;
```

This fails because date is `const`.

If you want the input parameter as `const` then you must return a new Date object. The one you passed in is `const` and cannot be altered.

```
Date addOneDay(const Date& date)
{ 
    Date d(date);
    d.day = date.day + 1;
    return d;
};
```

This inccurs the cost of a few temporary objects.

If you removed the `const` restriction, you could use the same date like so.

```
void addOneDay(Date& date)
{
    date.day += 1;       
};
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do it by returning a value.

Comment: then return a reference to your original date from `addOneDay`.

Comment: @PaulRooney _"hen return a reference"_ Note that this won't work for the `const Date&` version again.

Comment: Absolutely. I was only suggesting that for the non `const`

Answer (score 3):

> *"How do I manipulate the data in the struct to get addOneDay to work?"*

It doesn't work, because you pass a `const` reference parameter, which actually means the parameter cannot be changed. The solution is to actually use the `return` value

```
Date addOneDay(const Date& date);

Date addOneDay(const Date& date) {
    Date rdate(date);
    rdate.day = rdate.day + 1;
    return rdate;
};
```

Comment: I couldn't get either of these to work in Xcode. It wants "date.day =+ 1".

Comment: @TimElhajj _"It wants `date.day =+ 1`."_ Uhm, what? Are you sure we're talking about c++ and not objective-c or something? Also why did you accept the other answer then, which proposes exactly the same?

Comment: I see now that I was mistaken. My apologies. When I attempted to implement this yesterday, I failed, but it was my fault in implementation, not anything you wrote.